# If Naga dies does Korra die too?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

When an Avatar is born they usually have some sort of animal guide usually associated with their background element and what nation they are born into when there predecessor dies. I am wondering if when the Avatar dies, does there animal guide die too. What prompted my question was when I was looking over Avatar the last Airbender, it seems to me that that the animal guide always dies with them instead of Avatar dieing first and then there animal guide dies.

It is most likely that there animal guide dies at the same time as the Avatar since they share a mutual link, but i was just wondering if the Avatar's animal guide dies then does that Avatar die too?

Comment: *Always*? Roku and Fang are the *only* ones we see die at the same time, and that was because they were together at the time. We have no information on the deaths of Appa or Momo.

Comment: My question does not ask information on Appa or Momo. It asks simply is it possible that if their animal companions dies, does the Avatar die simply because of the mutual bonds that they share?

Comment: *"it seems to me that that the animal guide always dies with them instead of Avatar dieing first and then there animal guide dies."* The ONLY thing to back up this claim is when Roku and Fang die at the same time - when they're together. You're not asking for information about Appa or Momo, but you're assuming it. Your entire premise is faulty.

Comment: Your not answering my question, your just going right around it and not using your imagination. Try not thinking logically but Avatarly within the Avatar World and its possibilities.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Avatar is **not** bonded with an animal companion at birth. Roku found Fang when Fang was an egg. Airbenders at Aang's temple *all* bonded with sky bison at ~6 years old, regardless of being the Avatar or not. Korra rescued Naga when Naga became lost in the tundra near the Southern Water Tribe. Mula bonded with Wan *before* he became the Avatar, although Wan is an exceptional circumstance, since he was the first.

Worth noting: Naga, Appa, Fang, and Mula are the *only* animal companions we've seen.

The only on-screen Avatar/companion death was Roku and Fang, who died together fighting against a volcanic eruption. (Roku fell, Fang wrapped himself around Roku, and then lava washed over them both.) We do see Wan's death, but Mula is absent from the scene; whether she had already died (from old age or otherwise) or was simply not present at Wan's death is unknown. Aang died of old age (66 biologically, 166 chronologically), but we don't know if Appa died before, with, or after him.

Comment: When did we learn Aang's age of death?  Or is that derived by comparing Korra's age to other dates?  I always thought we didn't know how long Aang ultimately lived.

Comment: @Nerrolken, Aang was biologially 12 when he was found in the pilot, the original series took place over the course of approximately one year, and Legend of Korra takes place 70 years later, with Korra being 17 years old. 12+1+70-17=66